# How do I automatically number headings in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word: continued title numbering](https://superuser.com/questions/16233/word-continued-title-numbering)

I have a Microsoft Word document which consists of (more or less) the following heading structure (this is just the heading structure, not the actual content of the document. I have some text bellow each heading):

```
heading 1
    heading 1.1
    heading 1.2
        heading 1.2.1
        heading 1.2.2
heading 2
    heading 2.1
    heading 2.2
        heading 2.2.1
        heading 2.2.2
    heading 2.3
heading 3
heading 4
    heading 4.1
        heading 4.1.1
```

etc.

**EDIT:** headings 1,2,3,4 are of type heading 1, headings 1.x, 2.x, 3.x, 4.x are of type heading 2 and headings 1.x.y, 2.x.y, 3.x.y, 4.x.y are of type heading 3.

I would like to automatically change the text of each heading so that I'll have them all numbered. In the above example I would expect the heading structure to look like this:

```
1. heading 1
    1.1. heading 1.1
    1.2. heading 1.2
        1.2.1. heading 1.2.1
        1.2.2. heading 1.2.2
2. heading 2
    2.1. heading 2.1
    2.2. heading 2.2
        2.2.1. heading 2.2.1
        2.2.2 heading 2.2.2
    2.3. heading 2.3
3. heading 3
4. heading 4
    4.1. heading 4.1
        4.1.1 heading 4.1.1
```

How do I do this in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Is the "heading" you have typed above an actual section title unique to each section, or is it just as typed, "heading"?

Comment: @music: It's actual heading. headings 1,2,3,4 are of type heading 1, headings 1.x, 2.x, 3.x, 4.x are of type heading 2 and headings 1.x.y, 2.x.y, 3.x.y, 4.x.y are of type heading 3.

Comment: After staring at Word 2010 and repeating "You gotta be kidding me" in my mind, I found that the easiest way to get correct multi-level numbering in a Word document is to open .docx in OpenOffice 4 and assign multi-level numbering to the 1st heading. It does the rest automatically. Then save as .doc (OO wants to save as .odt) and voila.

Answer (score 2):

Using Office 2007 goto Paragraph then Multilevel list on the ribbon. You can customise the numbering to what you require under Define New Multilevel List.

[image]

You may want to take a look at this video [Settings Headings and Numeration [Word 2007-10]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4hxgh1faEU)

Comment: And you would have to repeat that for every heading in the document. And then it will sequentially number all headings regardless of the level. Been there done that not going back.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Multilevel List style. The format you want is not the default outline format but you can change it by selecting the text you want outlined and then clicking the Multilevel List button which is located in the Paragraph section of the Home tab on the ribbon.  Your format is one of the options it presents.

As you type, use `Tab` on a new line to indent to the next deeper outline level and use `Alt-Tab` to shift the indent back to the previous outline level.  Word will automatically enter the outline numbering based on your indentation level.

**EDIT:**
In response to your comment / edit, You will probably need to define a new Multilevel list.  I don't think any of the builtins will do what you want.

When you click on the submenu arrow on the Multilevel List button in the Paragraph group (not the button itself), there's the option to define a New Multilevel List.  Here you can set outlining definitions and apply them to different global styles (click the More button to reveal the full options).

Click on a number list at the left of this window to select which level you want to edit and you can define the number style for it, and also link it to your heading styles.

That's about as close as you're going to get with builtin Word functionality.  If some incantation within those options doesn't work for you then you're probably left with writing a macro or looking for an add-in that will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not with indentation and not with how to create a list. Below each heading I also have content, so I cannot just select all headings and apply the multilevel list style to all of them. The example in my question is just the heading **structure**, not the content of the document. I'm asking how do I apply the multilevel list style to each line which is a heading.

Comment: @snakile See my edit.

Comment: In order to use the automated heading styles, you'll have to use the the word heading style modifier. That is the only automatic word process that does this. If you're just looking to add those numbers to the front of the heading line, the quickest thing is just to add them yourself.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of trouble for a trivial task that worked automatically out of the box in Word 97 and 2000. See my comment on the OP for the solution. I can't post an answer dunno why.